# uvch264src stalls when capturing from Logitech C920 in darkness

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, h.264, logitech

I have a gstreamer pipeline - running on this environment:

- Raspberry Pi 3
- Class 10 Sandisk 8GB sdcard
- Raspbian Jessie, all updated
- Logitech C920 USB 2 webcam
- Gstreamer 1.8 compiled from source
- No additional USB peripherals or devices
- 2A Apple USB Power Supply (iPad charger)
- Tested both with and without powered USB hub to connect the C920

It captures H264 footage (H264.720@24FPS). 
My pipeline takes the C920's H264 encoded output, and tees it. It also captures (alsa) the C920's audio, compresses it to AAC, and tee's that. One leg of both tees goes straight into an FLV muxer, then onto disk for backup.
The second leg of the tee's gets decoded (using OpenMax), then recompressed at a lower bitrate (again, OpenMax), and finally, FLV muxed, and pushed to an RTMP server for live viewing.

Ultimately, the result looks basically like this:

[image]

CPU sits at around 50% out of 400% (quad core remember:))

Now for the fun part...

I had all this working - perfectly. Then I shut it all down, and took a reward break. I came back to it in the evening, booted the code... and it ran for about 10 seconds, then the pipeline stalled. It didn't stop, pause, or error - it just stalled - packets stopped being written to disk and the stream.

There were some warnings and errors, but I had seen these before and they had no impact on the resulting stream, but now, for some reason - they were terminal to the health of the pipeline:

```
0:01:31.219560984  4075  0x1445400 WARN            audiobasesrc gstaudiobasesrc.c:864:gst_audio_base_src_create:<alsasrc0> create DISCONT of 708160 samples at sample 2904320
0:01:31.219736087  4075  0x1445400 WARN            audiobasesrc gstaudiobasesrc.c:869:gst_audio_base_src_create:<alsasrc0> warning: Can't record audio fast enough
0:01:31.219774941  4075  0x1445400 WARN            audiobasesrc gstaudiobasesrc.c:869:gst_audio_base_src_create:<alsasrc0> warning: Dropped 708160 samples. This is most likely because downstream can't keep up and is consuming samples too slowly.
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0: Can't record audio fast enough
Additional debug info:
gstaudiobasesrc.c(869): gst_audio_base_src_create (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0:
Dropped 708160 samples. This is most likely because downstream can't keep up and is consuming samples too slowly.
```

So, after pulling out what little hair I have left, I packed it up and called it a night.
This morning, I grabbed it again, ready to start afresh. I boot the code, and... it's working again... no hiccups!! What's going on here???

The only thing that has changed between it working, not working, then working again - was the time of day!

Then I had an idea. I ran the code, for a few minutes. No hiccups, all is good... then, I put the camera inside my laptop bag, so it couldn't see anything. After 10 seconds, the pipeline stalled!!!

I simplified down the pipeline to just the filesink (removed the tee's, OMX elements, and rtmpsink), and re-ran the tests. This time it did not completely stall, but I got the "Can't record audio fast enough" warnings, and the resulting file had significant audio dropouts.

So - it seems, that the Logitech C920, when in a darkened environment, seems to choke up somehow.

Something else that I have noticed, not sure if this is related... but I always got some oscillating, high frequency noise (about 16khz) in my recordings. If I hold the camera up to my ear, I can actually hear the same tone being emitted from the camera. If I cover up the lens on the camera, the tone stops. If I turn off the auto-focus on the camera, AND set the absolute focus level to "0", then the noise *almost* goes away too.
I know this is not a dud camera, because I have about 6 of them, and they all behave the same way. I also know it's not a bad Raspberry Pi, because I've tried this on all of these

- 3 * Raspberry Pi 3
- 1 * Raspberry Pi 2 B+
- 2 * Raspberry Pi B+

Can anybody shed some light on this?

=====================================

Additional notes:

- Capturing mjpeg (not activating the h264 encoder on the camera) prevents the audible noise coming from the camera. Indicates noise is caused by the camera's DSP.
- Capturing mpjeg does something interesting... the resulting video file appears to have dropped a whole lot of frames during the time the camera was in darkness... so once it's in light again, the video is ahead of the audio by several seconds.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fix for this pushed to the latest 1.12 Gstreamer version that forces frames into the buffer even when the camera is on very long (black) exposures. We had a similar issue and a patch was suggested.
See the Gstreamer freedesktop site. 
You may need to recompile gstreamer-plugins-bad from source or wait until debian experimental packaging processes it. The file you want is libgstuvch264.so and the uograde is to mjpeg_demux.c in the sys/uvch264src subfolder. 
Note the fix is only 5-6 days old.

Comment: Hi Mark - are you sure about this? The issue report pertains to H264 streams, not the mjpeg one. Can you provide a link to the patch? I don't see anything relevant here: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/commits/1.12/sys/uvch264/gstuvch264_mjpgdemux.c

Comment: Certain about the issue and location - despite it says mjpeg_demux.c it handles all the camera streams. Need to double check whether it arrived. Will post patch here if not, but better if it comes through Gstreamer team.

Comment: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/master/sys/uvch264/gstuvch264_mjpgdemux.c
has the patch - if you look at lines 662 for about 30 lines you will see the effect on h264. Not sure your mirror is up to date with the main branch (commit 7 days ago).

Comment: Thanks Mark - I see it now in the master. This indeed looks like it will work. I had solved the issue by writing a custom element which corrected the DTS - will be nice to move to 1.12 when it's released. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar issues with the Logitech C920 using GStreamer and uvch264src.

The problem seems to be the frame rate. When it's dark, the camera will lower the frame rate and lengthen the exposure. This results in better lit frames, but the change really confuses GStreamer. I tried setting fixed-framerate=true and framerate=30/1, but that didn't help. The only thing that worked was disabling the camera auto exposure function.

v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -c exposure_auto_priority=0

It's not ideal (especially if you're dealing with variable lighting conditions), but at least the stream doesn't hang and audio and video stay in sync.