# What it the expected behavior when using the input Framerate option (in FFmpeg) when the input is a real-time camera device?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, frame-rate, v4l2, pts

As far as I know, the use of the *Framerate* option should be used only on an input files (like sequence of images or perhaps a video file that don't have a defined PTS).

However, if I run the command below on my web-cam, the video still streams fine (at least for a few hours from what I've checked till now). Why is that still works? Should I expect that something will get wrong? (maybe later, after a few hours or days of streaming)

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -f v4l2 -copyts -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -r 30 -f mpegts udp://192.168.10.199:1234
```

EDIT:

After running some more tests, it seems that when I'm running the command like this, the steam get stuck after a few hours:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -f v4l2 -copyts -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -r 30 -f mpegts udp://192.168.10.199:1234
```

However, if I run the command like this, it runs for days:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -f v4l2 -copyts -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -r 30 -f mpegts udp://192.168.10.199:1234
```

But I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

The framerate option causes your camera stream to be resampled at a fixed sample rate (here 30 fps). This will inevitably results in doubled and/or missed frames, or even judder. Do not use this option here.

Comment: For v4l2, framerate is passed back to the capture driver. FFmpeg on its part will not drop or dupe frames.

Comment: The reason I'm using -framerate and not -r, is because I'm trying to use the -copyts option, and it works only with -framerate. However, when I'm using -r and -copyts, it somehow ignores the -copyts option. So, is it ok I'm using the -framerate option ?

Answer (score 0):

Some cameras support multiple frame rates and `-framerate` allows you to choose which frame rate you want. You can list such info with `v4l2-ctl`:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
            Size: Discrete 640x480
                    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
            Size: Discrete 352x288
                    Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                    Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                    Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                    Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
```

If you choose an invalid frame rate then you'll get a message:

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x556d45e42180] The driver changed the time per frame from 1/12 to 1/10
```

So the worst that can happen (when using 4vl2 at least) is that your camera simply uses a different, but still supported frame rate.

See the [FFmpeg v4l2 input device documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#video4linux2_002c-v4l2) for more info and additional options.

Be warned that framerate value can change in time [because of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42676897/7915017) exposure.

Comment: I think your last explanation also valid for the -r option, but I'm not exactly understand what is the difference between the two, and why the -framerate option causes me problems after a few hours.

Comment: @JosephMatan What are the errors? What version of ffmpeg are you using?

Comment: That the weird thing... No errors. The frame counter just stops counting, and FPS decrease to 0.0. (I'm using the latest FFmpeg from master)

Comment: @JosephMatan Need a process of elimination. The network output may be having an issue. Does outputting to a local, normal file work as expected? If yes, then it problem is likely not the v4l2 input but the UDP output.